# pyqt pushButton and toolButton menu

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

i am trying to create dropdown menu in pushButton and toolButton in pyqt5. how it is possible to make dropdown without "down arrow" icon. and while i click pushButton dropdown appear quickly but in tool button it's not working properly. i have to press down few seconds than dropdown will appear.

here the codes:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QWidget,QPushButton,QMenu,QDesktopWidget
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 170, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.toolButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.toolButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 170, 61, 31))
        self.toolButton.setObjectName("toolButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        menu_items = [
            {'Source':['google','yahoo','Reuters',]},
           'test1',
           'test2',
           'test3',
        ]
        menu =QMenu()
        menu.triggered.connect(lambda x:print(x.text()))
        self.add_menu(menu_items,menu)

        self.pushButton.setMenu(menu)
        self.toolButton.setMenu(menu)

    def add_menu(self,data,menu_obj):
        if isinstance(data,dict):
                for k,v in data.items(): 
                        sub_menu = QMenu(k,menu_obj)
                        menu_obj.addMenu(sub_menu)
                        self.add_menu(v,sub_menu)
        elif isinstance(data,list):
                for element in data:
                        self.add_menu(element,menu_obj)
        else:
                action = menu_obj.addAction(data)
                action.setIconVisibleInMenu(False)   

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "pushButton"))
        self.toolButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "toolButton"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delay required for the QToolButton popup is the default behavior, documented in the [`popupMode()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbutton.html#popupMode-prop) property. If you want to display the menu instantly, just use `InstantPopup`:

```
self.toolButton.setPopupMode(QtWidgets.QToolButton.InstantPopup)
```

Note that this might still show a small arrow (or a very small square) on the right of the button in certain styles, whenever a menu is set for a QToolButton, and it probably won't prevent to show the arrow in any case with QPushButtons.

The solution is to disable the arrow indicator using a stylesheet.

You could set that application wide, so that any button with a menu won't show the arrow:

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyleSheet('QAbstractButton::menu-indicator { image: none; }')
```

Note that the above will apply to *any* QAbstractButton descendant (most importantly, QToolButton, QPushButton) but you could choose to set that for specific classes only:

```
app.setStyleSheet('QToolButton::menu-indicator { image: none; }')
```

Alternatively, you can set the stylesheet for individual buttons:

```
self.toolButton.setStyleSheet('QToolButton::menu-indicator { image: none; }')
# this also works
self.toolButton.setStyleSheet('::menu-indicator { image: none; }')
```